# Laravel Mail not rendering properly

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-6

I have the issue in which when I am writing the components in Laravel Mailable, according to their 6.x documentation (since my Laravel version is 6.0). But despite that, in the actual email some components render properly, some are just plain HTML. By plain HTML I mean the text literally says `<a>...</a>`, but doesn't render the actual element.

Why would that be? Maybe there is a bug, or I am missing something? I have written the most regular email with the components provided by Laravel's docs. There is no linter errors. The  view is written in blade btw.

```
@section('content')
    @foreach ($paragraphs as $item)
        <p> {{ $item }} </p>
    @endforeach

    @component('mail::button', [ 'url' => $link ])
        {{ $buttonText }}
    @endcomponent
@endsection
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved the issue. The issue disappeared when I removed any possible indentation in the file.
When every single line started at column 0, the components rendered properly.

Documentation (at least 6.x) doesn't say anything about that, so I assume this is a bug with blade/php mailing compilation or something.

Comment: the docs are now a bit clearer https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#writing-markdown-messages